# how do i pre fill a form field with a models object in django

Tags: python, django

i have two pages profile and add notes. i want to fill the patient field in the add notes form with the users first name whenever i click add notes on any users profile will i need to change the url path? if yes, how do i get the data from the url and fill it in the form.

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', dashboard, name='dashboard'),
    path('profile/', profile, name='profile'),
    path('profile/<str:slug>/<int:pk>', profile, name='profilepk'),
    path('edit_profile/<int:id>/', edit_profile, name='editprofile'),
    path('addnotes/', addnotes, name='addnote'),
  
]
```

views.py

```
def addnotes(request):
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user_id=id)
    form = PatientNotesForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect(f'/dashboard/profile/{user.profile.slug}/{user.pk}')

    return render(request, 'core/addnotes.html', {'form': form})

def profile(request, slug, pk):
    profil = Profile.objects.get(slug=slug)
    profile = Profile.objects.get(pk=pk)
    context = {'profile': profile, 'profil': profil}
    return render(request, 'dashboard/profile.html', context)
```

models.py

```
class Note(models.Model):
    illness = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='patientnote', null=True)
    Doctor = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    Description = models.CharField(max_length=10000, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.illness}"
```

forms.py

```
class PatientNotesForm(ModelForm):
    illness = forms.CharField(max_length=100, help_text='First Name')
    patient = forms.CharField(max_length=100, help_text='Last Name')
    doctor = forms.CharField(max_length=100, help_text='address')
    description =  forms.CharField(max_length=100,widget=forms.Textarea)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['illness'].widget.attrs.update(
            {'placeholder': ('illness')})
        self.fields['doctor'].widget.attrs.update(
            {'placeholder': ("Doctor's name")})
        self.fields['patient'].widget.attrs.update(
            {'placeholder': ("Patient's name")})
        self.fields['description'].widget.attrs.update(
            {'placeholder': ("Description")})
        self.fields['illness'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'log'})
        self.fields['doctor'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'log'})
        self.fields['patient'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'log'})
        self.fields['description'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'textarea'})

    class Meta:
        model = Note
        fields = ('illness', 'patient', 'doctor', 'description')
```

addnotes.html

```
   <form method="post" class="fum"> {%csrf_token%}{{form.illness}}{{form.patient}}{{form.doctor}}{{form.description}}
            <li class="btnn "><button type="submit " class="conf ">Confirm</button></li>
        </form>
```

profile.html

```
     <ul class="main-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="#"><img class="nav-items" src="{% static 'images/home.svg'%}" alt=""><span>Home</span></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><img class="nav-items" src="{% static 'images/male.svg'%}" alt=""><span>Patients</span></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><img class="nav-items" src="{% static 'images/doctor.svg'%}" alt=""><span>Add notes</span> </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><img class="nav-items" src="{% static 'images/lab.svg'%}" alt=""><span>Edit profile</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Where is the `id` in `user_id=id` coming from. Since that is not a parameter, it will use the `id` builtin function, which will not work.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem that line doesn't matter. I Forgot to get rid of it.

Comment: but I'm not talking about the `editprofile`, but about the `addnotes`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear if the form should *contain* a field for `patient` in the first place. If the URL is constructed for a specific patient.

You should add this value somehow. For example in the path:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # &hellip;
    path('addnotes/<int:pk>', addnotes, name='addnote'),
]
```

Next we can decide to either prefill this in the form, or just omit the field.

## Option 1: omit the `patient` field

So in that case it means that the `ModelForm` looks like:

```
class PatientNotesForm(ModelForm):
    # …
    
    class Meta:
        model = Note
        #                 no patient ↓
        fields = ('illness', 'doctor', 'description')
```

In that case you can spec

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def addnotes(request, id):
    profile = get_object_or_404(Profile.objects.get, user_id=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':    
        form = PatientNotesForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.patient = profile
            form.save()
            return redirect(f'/dashboard/profile/{user.profile.slug}/{user.pk}')
    else:
        form = PatientNotesForm()
        form.instance.patient = profile
    return render(request, 'core/addnotes.html', {'form': form})
```

## Option 2: Prefill it in the form

An alternative is to still allow to modify this in the form, but specify an [**`intial=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.initial). In that case the `PatientNotesForm` remains the same but we pass an initial value.

```
def addnotes(request, id):
    if request.method == 'POST':    
        form = PatientNotesForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect(f'/dashboard/profile/{user.profile.slug}/{user.pk}')
    else:
        form = PatientNotesForm(initial={'patient': id})
    return render(request, 'core/addnotes.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: i need the patient field so that i can filter notes by the users(list out notes that belong to a user). currently i used option 2, but it doesn't save it keeps saying Cannot assign "'navabe'": "Note.patient" must be a "Profile" instance. navabe is the username

Comment: @blockhead: that is because you used a `CharField`, not a `ModelChoiceField`.

Comment: @blockhead: if you want to be able to enter a query, you can use `django-select2`: https://django-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ as widget, but the form field is still a `ModelChoiceField`, since that is what a `ForeignKey` expects.